# Kotlin: A bug that works with code in Kotlin version 1.4.30 but does not work with 1.5.2

Tags: java, kotlin, jetbrains-ide

It works well with Kotlin version 1.4.30 but not with version 1.5.x.

```kotlin
class Solution {

    fun solution(bricks: IntArray, n: Int, k: Int): Int {
        var answer: Int = 0
        var cloneBricks = bricks.clone()

        data class Brick(val height: Int, val index: Int)

        val brickList = bricks.mapIndexed { index, i ->
            Brick(i, index)
        }.toMutableList()

        brickList.sortBy {
            -it.height
        }

        fun getCountDoung(bArr: IntArray): Int {
            var prev = -1
            var cnt = 0

            for (i in bArr.indices) {
                //n-1
                if (bArr[i] >= n) {
                    if (prev == 0)
                        cnt++
                    prev = 1
                } else {
                    prev = 0
                }
            }
            if (prev == 0)
                cnt++
            return cnt
        }

        var currentCnt = 1
        var totalAddBrick = 0
        brickList.forEachIndexed { index, brick ->
            val demoBricks = cloneBricks.clone().apply { set(brick.index, n) }
            val cnt = getCountDoung(demoBricks)
            if (currentCnt < cnt) {
                currentCnt = cnt
                totalAddBrick += n - brick.height
                cloneBricks = demoBricks

                if (currentCnt == k) {
                    return totalAddBrick
                }
            }
        }

        return answer
    }
}


fun main() {

    Solution().run {

        solution(intArrayOf(0, 1, 2, 3, 4), 5,2).let {
            println(it)
        }
    }
}
```

The result of the above code outputs "2" (It runs well in version 1.4.30.)
Try it here, [link](https://play.kotlinlang.org/)

However, after updating to version 1.5, the error as below has occurred and it does not work!

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.VerifyError: Bad access to protected data in invokevirtual
Exception Details:
  Location:
    Solution.solution([III)I @257: invokevirtual
  Reason:
    Type 'java/lang/Object' (current frame, stack[0]) is not assignable to 'Solution'
  ...
```

I don't know why this error occurs.

I was wondering if there was a problem with the latest version of Kotlin because it was caused by updating the latest version of Kotlin.

Comment: I think this should be a bug in Kotlin. Please report through [YouTrack](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com).

Comment: @daylily Yes, I did.

Answer (score 1):

The code that produces bug is `val demoBricks = cloneBricks.clone().apply { set(brick.index, n) }`. The problem was fixed in KT-47499 and fix will be delivered in 1.6.0-M1. (@Ivan Kubyshkin)

[Sources](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-47728)